# How to get a result as CurrentDate - 14 Days

Tags: sql, datetime

I am using this query to get the result of a DateTime Dropdown.
Query is:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), PeriodStartDate, 106) AS PeriodStartDate
FROM PayPeriod
```

I want to populate it according to 14 days before current Date. 
Somewhat like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), PeriodStartDate, 106) AS PeriodStartDate
FROM PayPeriod
WHERE PeriodStartDate BETWEEN GETDATE() AND PeriodEndDate
```

Instead of **GetDate()**  how to write it as **GetDate() - 14Days** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `DATEADD` method.

```
DATEADD(DAY,-14,GETDATE())
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Use `DATEADD`:

```
DATEADD(day, -14, GETDATE())
```